# Generated zip file is always corrupted after download on Mac

Tags: java, zip, fileoutputstream, zipoutputstream

Lets say that I have a collection of objects which I would like to wrap with zip. My zip conversion class looks like:

```
public class ZipFile {

    public byte[] createZipByteArray(String fileName, byte[] content) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (byteArrayOutputStream; ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream)) {
            zipOutputStream.setLevel(Deflater.NO_COMPRESSION);
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            zipOutputStream.write(content);
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
            zipOutputStream.flush();
        }
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }

}
```

My controller looks like:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "objectWithDetails/zip", produces = "application/zip")
    @RolesAllowed("QUERY_DATA")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getObjectWithDetails(String limit, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/zip");

        List<ObjectSpecification> objectRepresentation = recipeService.getObjectRepresentation(limit);

        byte[] objectsBytes = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(objectRepresentation);

        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile();

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/zip"))
                .header("Content-Encoding", "UTF-8")
                .header("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"details_%s.zip\"", dateTimeProvider.nowDate()))
                .body(zipFile.createZipByteArray(String.format("details_%s.zip", dateTimeProvider.nowDate()), objectsBytes));

    }
```

In swagger, I have a download option for the generated zip files. After all, when I try to open the downloaded file I receive the following:

`Unable to expand filename.zip. It is in an unsupported format.`

I tried closing `ZipOutputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` in a different configuration. Applied a different option for the content type in the controller but still, I cannot find out why all zip files are corrupted. I will be grateful for suggestions on what I miss. Cheers!

Comment: How exactly did you try to open the downloaded file?

Comment: I am opening it via Archive Utility on mac. @BasilBourque

Comment: Have you tried using the DEFLATE method? It could be that the Mac doesn't recognise NO_COMPRESSION. Also, are you sure you want to name the zip entry "details_<date>.zip"? There are multiple problems with that. First, are you sure you want a zip file inside a zip file? If not, you should remove the ".zip" from the filename. Second, if the date contains "/" characters (such as "5/1/2023") then they will end up as subdirectories.

Comment: You are right @k314159, wrapping zip with zip was problematic. I posted an answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find out the root cause with @k314159
, namely, I had a zip file wrapped with a zip file. New version which works as expected.

```
    public static byte[] createZipByteArray(String fileName, byte[] content) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (byteArrayOutputStream; ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream)) {
            zipOutputStream.setLevel(Deflater.DEFLATED);
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            zipOutputStream.write(content);
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
            zipOutputStream.flush();
        }
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

and controller

```
    @GetMapping(value = "objectWithDetails", produces = "application/zip")
    @RolesAllowed("QUERY_DATA")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getObjectWithDetails(String limit, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/zip");
        List<ObjectSpecification > objectRepresentation = objectService.getObjectRepresentation(limit);

        byte[] objectsBytes = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(objectRepresentation);

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/zip"))
                .header("Content-Encoding", "UTF-8")
                .header("Content-Disposition", getObjectFileName("attachment; filename=objects_"))
                .body(createZipByteArray(getObjectFileName("objects_"), objectsBytes));
    }
```

Comment: By the way, I just noticed you're using `zipOutputStream.setLevel(Deflater.DEFLATED)` wrong. It should be `zipOutputStream.setMethod(Deflater.DEFLATED)`, since DEFLATED is a method, not a level. The level is just an integer between 0 and 9.